# TomEE - How does ClassLoader load from 3 webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, apache-tomee, tomee-8

I am working on deploying some of the existing web services to Apache TomEE 8. I have three webapps(EAR files) to deploy. I tried deploying each one of them independently and they are working fine and the class loader is able to load the necessary classes for that particular app.

But, when I try to deploy all three of them together, only one of the webapp is working properly and rest of the two are throwing internal server errors. When I look at the server logs, I see `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.example.classname` for the other two apps, But, when I go to `TomEE-8/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/classes/` , I am able to see the class that the exception is being thrown for.

So my question is How do I isolate classloader for each of the app and deploy all the three EARs together? I am new to Tomcat and TomEE and having a hard time figuring this out.

Below is my TomEE's directory structure for deployment:

1. For app1 - TomEE/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/app1class1.class
2. For app2 - TomEE/webapps/app2/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/app2class1.class
3. For app3 - TomEE/webapps/app3/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/app3class1.class

I have a common library `common.jar`, which the classloader should use for class loading, and I have placed in `TomEE/lib`. Rest of the configuration is the same as provided during installation.

For deployment, I am placing app1.ear, app2.ear and app3.ear files in the webapps directory and starting the server.

I expected all the three web services to be running but only one of them was running, presumably which was deployed first and the rest two are throwing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Can someone please help me with this? I have been trying to find any related issues and was not find any.

Edit-1:

Previous Liberty Server configuration:

```
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <library id="commonlib"><fileset dir="path/to/common.jar"/></library>

    <application location="path/to/app1.ear" id = "app1.ear"
    name="app1.ear" type="ear"><classloader commonLibraryRef="commonlib"/></application>

    <application location="path/to/app2.ear" id = "app2.ear"
    name="app2.ear" type="ear"><classloader commonLibraryRef="commonlib"/></application>

    <application location="path/to/app3.ear" id = "app3.ear"
    name="app3.ear" type="ear"><classloader commonLibraryRef="commonlib"/></application>
```

Comment: Why does the common jar need to go in tomee/lib? Why cant it be included inside each ear? What class is tomcat choking on and which artifact is it part of?

Comment: Also why you the tomee home directory is called TomEE-7 but you said it is version 8? Why your library is used for class loading?

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks for your reply. Just a little more context - I am trying to migrate from Liberty to TomEE and was trying to replicate the Liberty's configuration in TomEE. I have Edited the post with the Liberty's configuration. common.jar is a shared library and hence I put it in tomee/lib. For the classes that tomcat is choking on, when I deploy each of the ear independently, it is able to load the required classes for that app. But, when I deploy the three EARs together at the same time, tomcat is able to load classes for one of the app and it is always random on which one is working.

Comment: @aled Thanks for your reply. Sorry, it was a mistake. It is TomEE-8 and I edited the post. I am trying to migrate from Liberty to TomEE and trying to replicate Liberty's configuration which I edited in the post. Liberty was configured to use common.jar for classloading and hence I was trying to replicate it.

Comment: I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/58159342/217324, then follow the link to the tomcat classloader how-to doc. My guess is you need some extra configuration to match the liberty setup.

Comment: @NathanHughes I read the doc and tried configuring a shared classloader in the Catalina.properties file, but still the same issue. The thing is when deployed individually, all the apps are working fine. But when deployed together is the issue. Is this the issue with isolating the classloader? I am new to Tomcat and could not figure out what the issue here is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a silly mistake in providing the same ID to all the webapps in the WEB-INF/web.xml file. Because of this, TomEE is deploying the first app and since the second app is also having the same ID in web.xml, it is trying to find the class in the WEB-INF/classes folder of the first deployed app. Resolved by providing unique IDs to all the apps in the web.xml

Answer (score 0):

TomEE follows a tree classloading.
You can see the inherited tomcat one there (https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/developer/classloading/index.html) then for your app you get a common classloader (child of tomcat) and then one webapp classloader per webapp (child of common).

So you just have to put common in yourear/lib folder (see library-directory from application.xml for example - or something equivalent) and it should be fine.

If you intend to use common.loader to share your common jar you must also put its dependencies in tomcat/lib and just deploy the webapps as webapps and not as an ear.

Last note: you likely need to configure tomee.xml to enable ear deployment in apps/ and not use webapps/ which has a specific handling if not already done (theorically it should work but it has side effects so better to stay off it). You can also review https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/deployments.html if you prefer - it proposed alternative configurations.

What can happen if a common lib class can't be loaded so the webapp class can't be loaded transitively i nyour case.

Comment: Thanks Romain for your reply! So you are saying putting the common.jar in my ear/lib folder for all the EARs would resolve the issue?

Comment: I re-packaged my EARs to include common.jar, but still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you try reproducing in a small project on github (likely 4 modules: 1 lib with one class, 2 webapps using lib (can be the same code, just needs 2 modules, and last module to build the ear)? Another try can be to rename the common.jar to something like foo.jar too.